# Javascript add time interval to my onmouseover function

Tags: animation, hover, onmouseover

So I have this logo that I want it to become colored when mouse hovers over. I have the code for switching the pictures on mouse hover but I need the  element to change with a time interval. You can find the code I am using attached.

```
<a href="#page-top" class="Logo"><img id="logo" src="img/logocolored1.png" 
alt="Compositions" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function hover(element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'img/logocolored.png');
                 }
function unhover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', 'img/logocolored1.png');                                                
                                        }
</script></a>
```

Comment: You can't put a script element inside an anchor

Comment: My friend that is not the problem, you can do that and it works.

Comment: @FLash it may work, but it is definitely wrong, so don't do that. Specially if you want to get help from someone else.

Comment: @Matyas It may work, but it is definitely wrong.. Do realize how naive your view of coding is.... If it works it works.. Don't just stick to the books you read man up.

Comment: @FLash if you are not willing to listen, then don't ask :-) Using hammer for screwing is also possible, but it doesn't make it the good, efficient way. There is nothing naive about that. What I find naive is asking for help and ignoring facts.